# How to normalize colorbar in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to adjust colobar scale from my current figure[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83tYM.png) to the desired figure[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJhlp.png) !!

My colorbar scale range is -1 to 1, but I want it in exponential form and for that I tried levels = np.linspace(-100e-2,100e-2) as well, but it also doesn't give the desired scale[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJhlp.png)

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ds = xr.open_dataset('PL_Era_Tkt.nc')

wp = ds.w.mean(dim=['longitude','latitude']).plot.contourf(x='time',cmap='RdBu',add_colorbar=False,extend='both')
wpcb = plt.colorbar(wp)
wpcb.set_label(label='Pa.s${^{-1}}$',size=13)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.title('Vertical Velocity',size=15)
```

My current scale

[image: my figure]

My desired scale

[image]

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in this question. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Maybe you're using matplotlib?

Answer (score 1):

Since the data is not presented, I added normalized color bars with the data from the graph [sample here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.04-density-and-contour-plots.html). I think the color bar scales will also be in log format with this setup. Please note that the data used is not large, so I have not been able to confirm this.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np
plt.style.use('seaborn-white')

def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(x) ** 10 + np.cos(10 + y * x) * np.cos(x)

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 50)
y = np.linspace(0, 5, 40)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X, Y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, 20, cmap='RdGy')

cmap = mpl.cm.RdGy
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=-1, vmax=1.0)

fig.colorbar(mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap),
             ax=ax, orientation='vertical', label='Some Units', extend='both', ticks=ticker.LogLocator())

plt.show()
```

[image]